# Should a node (vertex) know about its neighbours in a graph?

Tags: dart, graph, vertex, neighbours, edge-list

I am trying to implement a graph in dart.

I thought of creating the classes Node (vertex), Edge and Graph.

The main idea is that the Graph has a List of Nodes and a List of Edges.

Later I will implement some search algorithms on the graph.

I think of also adding a List of neighbours to each Node (List neighbours) so each Node knows its neighbours (successor nodes to be precise) . My thought here is that getting the successor nodes of one node is quicker when the node has this information than when the algorithm has to check the edge list each time. I know that changes (deletion of edges, nodes, adding new edges, node) would also cost more because I'd have to update them in two locations. But at the moment I don't plan to make the graph too dynamic after its creation.

Do you think this approach makes sense or might my way have some mayor flaw?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't that question get more attention on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're not changing the graph once it's created, by denormalizing the graph you're creating `Technical Debt`, making it more complicated/difficult to work on. You could get some weird bugs that would be hard to track down. When you come back to this piece of code in a month or two it'll be a little more confusing since it's not fresh in your memory and it's not intuitive.

You would have to have an absurd amount of nodes to realize any performance gain and if you had an absurd amount of nodes you'd be doubling the amount of references to the edges, increasing the memory footprint. Also if you're compiling to JavaScript, be nice to the garbage collector by not having more references to an object than you need.

If you want to improve the performance of the graph I'd look into what I could run concurrently with isolates. Just keep in mind, graphs can get stupid complex so if you can keep anything simple, then keep it simple.